# How to create two browser pages in one with html

Tags: html

We learned this in web design class last year and I do not remember how, What I want to do is create a webpage so that its split down the middle, and has a different webpage on each side, so I could watch you tube on the right side and Google on the other without them affecting the other. If the size bar was re-adjustable would be nice. Please could anyone help.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/frameset

Comment: frames :) google it pls

Comment: Use frames; they use the `frameset` and `frame` elements; check out the link SLaks posted for details. Each page you want to display is one frame.

Comment: Please note: Frames are depreciated and will not be included in HTML5, you should start resorting to iframe (which is annoying)

Answer (score 3):

You can creat two columns with css and then your can use `<iframe>` tag

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="left">
<iframe ....../>
</div>
<div class="right">
<iframe ...../>
</div>
</div>
```

Then two pages will be along side of each others.

Answer (score 0):

Just to explain further on the previous answer:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div align="left">
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com"/>
<div>
<div align="right">
<iframe src="http://www.google.com"/>
</div>
</div>
```

- An `iframe` is what contains the webpage
- A `div` can align parts of a webpage according to the `align` attribute
   
  (NOTE: align will not be supported in HTML5, so you should use CSS to align instead)

I hope this explained things a bit better, and helped you out! :)